# How to avoid using "and" in Objective-C method name

Tags: objective-c, naming

I have this method in my `NDVector` class which finds the angle between two vectors along two axes (for 3D vectors this means you can find the angle between them just in terms of their X and Y components, X and Z components, or Y and Z components):

```
- (float) angleBetweenThisAnd: (NDVector *) vector2 byAxis: (NSUInteger) axis1 and: (NSUInteger) axis2;
```

I don't think I'm utilizing the descriptive naming you can do with methods which take multiple parameters in Objective-C. I find myself doing this a lot, really. I think of the method, say it as a sentence which doesn't state the relationship between its subject and its verb in plain English (i.e. `[someVector angleBetweenThisAnd: otherVec ...]` instead of `[someVector findsAngleBetweenItselfAnd: otherVec ...]`) and then write it as the method name, but it seems so redundant to say "and" in the name of a method. I mean of course it's and!

In Java, naming methods was a lot simpler, but in Objective-C, I'm confused by the close relationship between plain English and code in method names. Most importantly, is there a common way to avoid using "and" in the name of a method?

Comment: Your method only receives one vector...

Comment: @nickfalk but it takes two axes, and that's where the "and" is

Comment: Maybe there is "too much" English at times in Obj-C? Consider `float angleBetween: Vector axis1: Axis axis2: Axis` has the "simple" Java signature mapping of `float angleBetween(Vector v, Axis axis1, Axis axis2)`.

Comment: How about `angleAtIntersectionWith:inPlaneFirstAxis:secondAxis:` - "with" is often used to mean "self and".

Comment: `-(CGFloat) angleBetweenVector:axis1:axis2` should fit Cocoa-conventions quite nicely and read equally well methinks...

Comment: @CRD I was thinking about that approach. I like adding the fact that it's a plane as a description, but it would be nice to not have to name that plane something like `inPlaneFirstAxis:secondAxis` because the secondAxis is also part of the plane. But as I wrote that, I think I decided that I will make a new class, `NDPlane` which takes two `NSUInteger` arguments and that should solve the dilemma. It would be better as a struct, actually, since it doesn't do anything besides say which axes it contains. Can I define a struct in it's own file? Alright, I'm off to google.

Comment: This question is not primarily opinion-based. I'm asking for an array of solutions. Why can't I ask a question that doesn't have a single, exclusive answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at some of the NSDate comparison methods for inspiration.

For example, following a pattern like `timeIntervalSinceDate:` or `descriptionWithCalendarFormat:timeZone:locale:`, how about `[NDVector angleWhenIntersectingWithVector:axis1:axis2]`?

This could look like:

```
- (float) angleWhenIntersectingWithVector:(NDVector *)vector2
                                    axis1:(NSUInteger)axis1
                                    axis2:(NSUInteger)axis2;
```

Comment: Perfect. The key here is that "this" or "self" is implied (or, really, it's there in the message send syntax), so you don't need the "and" either.

Comment: Yeah, I like the use of with to imply with self

Comment: Note that if `axis1` and `axis2` are interchangeable without affecting the return value, you can just use the `axis:` keyword twice (while still naming the arguments differently), like `angleWhenIntersectingWithVector:(NDVector * )vector2 axis:(NSUInteger)axis1 axis:(NSUInteger)axis2`.  The method [`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:withObject:) does this.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to write method parameters that have no name. This is uncommon, but is occasionally the cleanest way to style the code.

```
- (float) angleWithVector:(NDVector *)vector2 axes:(NSUInteger)axis1 :(NSUInteger)axis2;

[vector angleWithVector:otherVector axes:b :K]

@selector(angleWithVector:axes::)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your method you made, you're really not being descriptive with the method itself. You are correct, using "and" is never good, using "and" as a parameter description is horrible. Think of it this way, if you don't have the input parameters named, how can you (or someone else) tell what it is (i.e., inline in code)?

For example:
- (float) angleBetweenThisAnd:  byAxis:  and:

in use:
[currentThing angleBetweenThisAnd:myVec  byAxis:b  and:K];

What is "this" in the first input parameter? What should I pass to "and"??? What is an "and" value supposed to be? Maybe you're the only one using your code, but time will come you haven't looked at it and forget how it works.

Think about putting a descriptive word in the method name. By having the method names with descriptive text, anyone else can read it, especially when you call it in code, since the values won't have their types or default names. I would rewrite your method as such:

-(float)angleBetweenVector2:(NDVector *)vector2 withAxis1:(NSUInteger)axis1 withAxis2:(NSUInteger)axis2;

Answer (score 0):

Another approach addressing the title question is to ask

*"How does the signature work when there are no argument names"*

So your original version.

`angleBetweenThisAnd:byAxis:and:` doesn't scan so well.

Whereas Aaron's version does…

`angleWhenIntersectingWithVector:axis1:axis2:`

The method signature now gives a clear indication of what it does without embedding info in the arg names.

Answer (score 0):

After your comment: If you have the freedom you could use an enumeration rather than a struct:

```
typedef enum { XAxis = 1,
               YAxis = 2,
               ZAxis = 4,
               XYPlane = 3,
               XZPlane = 5,
               YZPlane = 6
             } AxisOrPlane;

- (float) angleAtIntersectionWith:(NDVector *)vector inPlane:(AxisOrPlane)plane
```

The enumeration values have been picked so `XYPlane` is equivalent to `XAxis | YAxis` etc., but you don't need to do that.

A struct will of course work as well, for example:

```
typedef struct { NSUInteger axis1; NSUInteger axis2; } Plane;

- (CGFloat) angleAtIntersectionWith:(NSArray *)vector inPlane:(Plane)plane
```

and when calling the method you can use a structure literal:

[aVector angleAtIntersectionWith:anotherVector inPlane:(Plane){XAxis,ZAxis}];

where `XAxis` and `YAxis` are defined appropriately.

HTH

Comment: I like this answer, but unfortunately, it has to be an NDPlane, so I can't number out my axes like this (the number would stretch on to infinity). If you've got a solution to that (I can't think of any), then I agree that your method is much, much, better.

Comment: @doctordoder - How many dimensions do you have? An enumeration could cope with 64, but you would want to list out all possible 2016 pairs as enumeration constants (but you could write some code to write the enum declaration for you...)! Sounds like a struct is the way to go, just remember the structure literal (`(NDPlane){axis1, axis2}`) as an easy way to create the struct values.

Comment: Theoretically, it should support infinite (it'll probably crash after 13), but that struct literal syntax looks perfect for me!